# K-means clustering for VGG features is not working

Tags: arrays, scikit-learn, neural-network, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a multi-dimensional array of size 37759x4096. 37759 is the number of features observations and each feature is of size 4096.

These features are **vgg features** of images that I extracted for 37759 inages.  I wanted to perform k-means clustering to see if they would group among same classes.

code snippet:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

features = np.asarray(features) #converting list to features
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=17).fit(features)
```

output:

```
 In [26]: kmeans.labels_
Out[26]: array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 11, 11, 11], dtype=int32)

In [27]: len(kmeans.labels_)
Out[27]: 37759

In [28]: kmeans.cluster_centers_
Out[28]: 
array([[  2.46095985e-01,  -4.32133675e-07,   6.41381502e-01, ...,
          9.16770659e-09,   2.39292532e-03,   9.38249767e-01],
       [  1.18244767e+00,   8.83443374e-03,   8.44059408e-01, ...,
          6.17001206e-09,   7.23063201e-03,   4.57734227e-01],
       [  5.05003333e-01,   2.45869160e-07,   1.07537758e+00, ...,
         -4.24915925e-09,   2.19564766e-01,   6.04652226e-01],
       ..., 
       [  2.72164375e-01,   7.94929452e-03,   8.18695068e-01, ...,
         -3.43425199e-09,   7.62813538e-03,   2.84249210e+00],
       [  1.03947210e+00,   1.03959814e-04,   7.81472027e-01, ...,
          7.42147677e-09,   1.28777415e-01,   8.22515607e-01],
       [  1.55310243e-01,   6.24559261e-02,   7.55328536e-01, ...,
         -3.84170562e-09,   2.09998786e-02,   4.18608427e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

First of all, since it is a high-dimensional data I am not sure if k-means is the best way to go about it. It classified only 11 clusters instead of 17.
But anyway,

1. How can we ensure that it is clustering the arrays row-wise(according to sample observations) and not columnwise(features)
2. Features of same classes are stacked together, but we can see that in `kmeans.cluster_centers_` the cluster centers are very different, inferring from the first three arrays
3. How can I visualize this data? How do I find unique arrays?
4. Do you have any lead on how can I perform clustering for very high dimensional data such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clusters in kmeans can become empty and thus disappear.

If this happens, the initial centers were badly chosen, and often the result is not "stable". If you try different initial seeds, you will likely get very different results.

Clustering and visualizing such data is difficult, and you won't find an easy out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Agreed! I ended up looking at the covariances between inter and intra classes to make sure my numbers makes sense. Do you have comments about T-SNE for such high dimensional data?

Comment: t-SNE for clustering can be very misleading. See this excellent graphical answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264647/7828 that shows how t-SNE makes up "clusters" that weren't in the data.